# Compact the current database

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

Compact the current database, without closing it? Access 2016. VBA. 
As a friend said, you need to press to compress or restore database on the tape.

Answer (score 1):

True. Wonder have you can imagine it being compressed without being closed.

Answer (score 0):

When you press the compact and restore button, access actually closes the file, makes a copy, performs the compact and restore on the copy, then overwrites the original.
So sadly, you cant do what you want to do.